# Drupal 7 - Dynamic Allowed Values Field Widget

Tags: 7, entities

I have a project I'm working on where each content manager/author would have a different set of allowed values on a select input for each node created.  Is hook_form_alter the best method for me to dynamically generate the options?  And what would the syntax kind of look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might get it to work like so:

- Use the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module, and
- Integrate it in a form or module using a Forms API element.

More details below ...

## About this module

Here is an excerpt about the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module from its project page.

> Provides a new Forms API element which is a select/radios/checkboxes element that has an 'other' option. When 'other' is selected a textfield appears for the user to provide a custom value.

So basically you could "start" from a few options (Option 1, Option 2, Option 3), and whenever somebody needs another one (not in the list yet), they just enter "Option 4". Here is a sample about it:

[image]

## Integration in a form or module

By only using the module as delivered, you wouldn't have a different set of options yet for each author. But the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module can be integrated in any form or module, as shown also in the [usage example within the Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1158654) of this module.

By enhancing that usage example to make the values for `value_1`, `value_2`, `value_3` depend on each user, you should get it to work.